# A funny metric over $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, metric-spaces, p-adic

$\DeclareMathOperator{\lcm}{lcm}$
Fiddling with numbers I realized that for positive integers $x$ and $y$, the quantity
$$\Vert x,y \Vert=\frac{\lcm(x,y)}{\gcd(x,y)}$$
has these properties:

- $\Vert x,y \Vert=1\iff x=y$;
- $\Vert x,y \Vert \leq\Vert x,z\Vert\Vert z,y \Vert$ for any positive integer $z$.

In particular $\log\Vert x,y \Vert$ defines a metric over $\mathbb{N}^*$.

I couldn't find anything related online. Does anyone know if this $\Vert\cdot,\cdot\Vert$ operator appears somewhere in the literature? Or at least does it remind you of something, perhaps related to $p$-adic numbers?

Comment: I wonder if this metric gives the product topology on $\widehat{\mathbb Z} = \prod \mathbb Z_{(p)}$.

Comment: It ($\log ||\cdot||$) is the sum of all p-adic metrics.

Comment: Calling $\nu_p(x)$ the exponent of $p$ in the decomposition of $x$ as a product of prime numbers, one has $$\log\Vert x,y \Vert = \sum_{p \in \mathbb{P}} \log p \times |\nu_p(y)-\nu_p(x)|.$$

Comment: $d(x,y)=\sum_p|\nu_p(x)-\nu_p(y)|\log p$, so it's a "weighted" (but it's irrelevant, since every weight produces equivalent metric) taxicab metric on $c_{00}(\mathbb N)$, the space of eventually zero sequences of natural numbers

Comment: @DmitriiKorshunov it's not just a sum. Each one is weighted by $\log p$.

Comment: @LSpice how do you call that set?

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/461588/a-funny-metric-over-mathbbn#comment1197284_461588), do you mean $\widehat{\mathbb Z}$?  It's the pro-finite completion of $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: I dunno if it's known, but in general, for sets counting with multiplicity, the size of the XOR of two sets is also a metric

Comment: @MaartenHavinga in fact their mere XOR ($+$) defines a sort of metric in that $A+B=\emptyset\iff A=B$ and $A+B\subseteq (A+C)\cup (C+B)$ for all $C$. This "metric" can define a "metric" space. If the space is large enough, it will be $T_2$ but not first countable. For more detail on an essentially equal topology see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4834653/1157509).

Comment: Of potential interest is Dominici's CMJ piece, [**An Arithmetic Metric**](https://sci-hub.ee/10.4169/college.math.j.42.3.207).

Comment: This metric is tangentially mentioned in this questions: [A reinterpretation of the $abc$ - conjecture in terms of metric spaces?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/342652).
There are a few questions related to this metric on [math.se] (probably by the same user): 
[Does this completed metric space form a semi-ring?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3366568),
[Different proof for the inequality $b \gcd(a,c)^2+ a \gcd(b,c)^2-c \gcd(a,b)^2 \le abc$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3371958) and 
[Is there any use of metric spaces in number theory?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3359713).

Comment: @BenjaminDickman An arithmetric. The paper says "The diameter of $I_n$". Do you know what $I_n$ is?

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/461588/a-funny-metric-over-mathbbn#comment1197388_461588), I don't find the precise definition, but $I_{12} = \{1, 2, \dotsc, 12\}$ on p. 207 suggests that $I_n = \{1, \dotsc, n\}$.

Comment: @LSpice makes sense (the diameter he then gives goes accordingly)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This metric is mentioned in the [*Encyclopedia of distances*](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-30958-8) (Chapter 10.3), written by Michel Marie Deza and Elena Deza. Here is the relevant paragraph:$\newcommand{\lcm}{\operatorname{lcm}}$

> Let $\mathbb{L}= (L,\preceq,\vee, \wedge)$ be a lattice, and let $v$ be an isotone subvaluation on $\mathbb{L}$. The *lattice subvaluation semimetric* $d_v$ on $L$ is defined by $$2v(x \vee y)-v(x)-v(y).$$ (It can be defined also on some semilattices.) If $v$ is a positive subvalution on $\mathbb{L}$, one obtains a metric, called the **lattice subvaluation metric**. If $v$ is a valuation, $d_v$ is called the *valuation semimetric* and can be written as $$v(x \vee y)-v(x \wedge y)=v(x)+v(y)-2 v(x \vee y).$$ If $v$ is a positive valuation on $\mathbb{L}$, one obtains a metric, called the **lattice valuation metric**, and the lattice is called a **metric lattice**.
>
> If $L= \mathbb{N}$ (the set of positive integers), $x\vee y= \lcm(x,y)$ (least common multiple), $x\wedge y = \gcd(x,y)$ (greatest common divisor), and the positive valuation $v(x)= \ln x$, then $d_v(x,y)= \ln \frac{\lcm(x,y)}{\gcd(x,y)}$.
>
> This metric can be generalized on any *factorial* (i.e., having unique factorization) ring equipped with a positive valuation $v$ such that $v(x) \geq 0$ with equality only for the multiplicative unit of the ring, and $v(xy)=v(x)+v(y).$ Cf. **ring semimetric**.

Comment: (I found the same source by googling **"lcm(x,y)/gcd(x,y)" "metric"**)

Answer (score 7):

As [indicated](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/461588/a-funny-metric-over-mathbbn#comment1197378_461588) by @MartinSleziak the function

$$f(x,y):=\frac{xy}{\gcd(x,y)^2} = \frac{\operatorname{lcm}(x,y)}{\gcd(x,y)}$$

has interesting properties for example as indicated in [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/352054/the-abc-conjecture-as-an-inequality-for-inner-products) about the abc conjecture:

$$k(x,y):=1/f(x,y) = \frac{\gcd(x,y)^2}{xy}$$

is a positive definite kernel over the natural numbers.

(This can be seen directly by mapping the natural numbers into the Hilbert space of series as is being done in [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/449898/a-geometric-proof-that-there-are-infinitely-many-primes) :
Let $e_d$ be the $d$-th standard-basis vector in the Hilbert space $H=l_2(\mathbb{N})$.
Let $h(n)  = J_2(n)$ be the second Jordan totient function, defined by:

$$J_2(n) = n^2 \prod_{p|n}(1-1/p^2).$$
Define:

$$\phi(n) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{d|n}\sqrt{h(d)} e_d.$$

Then we have:

$$ \left < \phi(a),\phi(b) \right > = \frac{\gcd(a,b)^2}{ab}=:k(a,b).)$$

Another usage of the function $f$ that you indicate is to [make the unitary divisors into a boolean ring](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/369751/boolean-ring-of-unitary-divisors-structure-of-unitary-divisors):

Let $n$ be a natural number, $U_n := \{ d \mid d \text{ divides } n, \gcd(d,n/d)=1\}$ be the set of unitary divisors.

We can make $U_n$ into a boolean ring:

$$a \oplus b := \frac{ab}{\gcd(a,b)^2} = \frac{\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)}{\gcd(a,b)}$$
and
$$a \otimes b := \gcd(a,b).$$

Yet another nice proof, that the function $k$ is positive definite over the natural number, comes from [Rodrigo's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/343657/165920) to [Trigonometry / Euclidean Geometry for natural numbers?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/343479/trigonometry-euclidean-geometry-for-natural-numbers).

I have used this kernel to define the simplicity of ratio in music consonance:
[Measuring Note Similarity With Positive Definite Kernels](https://archive.org/details/measuring-note-similarity-with-positive-definite-kernels)
and generate algorithmic music based on this ([Sound of the nearest neighbors](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=quK3VCIhNOY)).

Another usage of this or related kernel is to generate formulas for the circle number $\pi$ as is being indicated here:
[Some Formulas For Pi](https://archive.org/details/some-formulas-for-pi/page/n5/mode/2up).

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer, but I was curious about the "shape" of numbers determined by this metric. Here's a [t-SNE plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-distributed_stochastic_neighbor_embedding) of the numbers from 1 to 256. As with any projection of this type, the geometry is quite distorted. But you can still make out some interesting structures, as in the cluster of numbers of the form $2^a3^b$ at lower right.

The numbers are colored by the log of the smallest prime factor. (Large primes faded out a bit, but you get the idea.)

[image]

Comment: Nice plot, You could also try UMAP for this.

Comment: It's interesting, I did try UMAP, and it had the same basic structure but the results were harder to read. For instance, the large primes all ended up in a kind of one-dimensional linear structure, which seemed slightly deceptive.

Comment: You might be interested in this plot: https://johnhw.github.io/umap_primes/index.md.html

Comment: Such a cool picture! And it seems like the metric there is in the same general family as this one, especially for square-free numbers.

Comment: Yes it looks like some sort of galaxy and yet these are "just" natural numbers! :-) Very cool.